# Dashboard moves/shakes continuously

Tags: thingsboard

It happens that sometimes the dashboard trembles.

Someone is able to tell me how can I resolve this?

thanks
Sarah

Comment: A workaround is to change the browser size, or to make it full screen. Another is to change the size or layout of widgets. Unfortunately, these workarounds doesn't solve the problem at all, only avoid this behaviour for a particular situation.